# Autofill form javascript didn`t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Last 2 rows from "request.done...." didn`t work... Just Nothing happen ... Everything else work

**This is my script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#retrieve-resources').click(function () {
        var displayResources = $('#display-resources');

        displayResources.text('Loading data from JSON source...');
        var url = "--------------------".concat(document.getElementById('title').value);

        $(document.getElementById("writer").value = '');
        $(document.getElementById("director").value = '');
        $(document.getElementById("actors").value = '');
        $(document.getElementById("year").value = '');
        $(document.getElementById("plot").value = '');
        $(document.getElementById("poster").value = '');


        var request = $.ajax({

            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"

        });

        request.done(function (result) {

            $(document.getElementById("writer").value = result.Writer.replace(new RegExp("\\s?\\(.*?\\)", "g"), ''));
            $(document.getElementById("director").value = result.Director.replace(new RegExp("\\s?\\(.*?\\)", "g"), ''));
            $(document.getElementById("actors").value = result.Actors.replace(new RegExp("\\s?\\(.*?\\)", "g"), ''));
            $(document.getElementById("year").value = result.Year);
            $(document.getElementById("poster").value = result.Poster.toString());
            displayResources.html('Form is filed!');
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry! This is my first question here... :/

Comment: Why are yuo wrapping `$(...)` around everything? Read a jQuery tutorial to see the correct way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have `$()` around each line. The argument to `$()` is supposed to be a selector, HTML string, or function. You were probably getting errors when it tried to parse the values that you were assigning.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#retrieve-resources').click(function () {
        var displayResources = '#display-resources';

        displayResources.text('Loading data from JSON source...');
        var url = "--------------------".concat(document.getElementById('title').value);

        document.getElementById("writer").value = '';
        document.getElementById("director").value = '';
        document.getElementById("actors").value = '';
        document.getElementById("year").value = '';
        document.getElementById("plot").value = '';
        document.getElementById("poster").value = '';

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        });

        request.done(function (result) {
            document.getElementById("writer").value = result.Writer.replace(new RegExp("\\s?\\(.*?\\)", "g"), '');
            document.getElementById("director").value = result.Director.replace(new RegExp("\\s?\\(.*?\\)", "g"), '');
            document.getElementById("actors").value = result.Actors.replace(new RegExp("\\s?\\(.*?\\)", "g"), '');
            document.getElementById("year").value = result.Year;
            document.getElementById("poster").value = result.Poster.toString();
            displayResources.html('Form is filed!');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of an element with jQuery you should use the `.val` function. For example, instead of using the code below to set the value of the element with id `writer` to an empty string:

```
$(document.getElementById("writer").value = '');
```

You should use this jQuery selector and `.val`:

```
$('#writer').val('');
```